# Creating Exchange account for user of subdomain

Tags: active-directory, exchange, domain-controller

We have a W2008R2  server which serves as AD DC for `intra.contoso.com` and Exchange server.

We have a W2012 server which serves as AD DC for subdomain `sub.intra.contoso.com` (which is *not* a new forest)

Now I managed to change the subdomain's password policy to create a new user, which is now logged in on a `intra.contoso.com` workstation as SUB\username. INTRA\someuser even managed to give SUB\username the right to access someuser's personal folder.

On the W2008R2 server, I now try to add an Exchange account for SUB\username. I can select SUB\username from the user list, but when I click "Finish", I get an error message stating that "in domain DC=sub,DC=intra,DC=contoso,DC=com no domain controller could be found" when trying to execute "Enable-Mailbox -Identity 'sub.intra.contoso.com/Users/username' -Alias 'username'.

Is it possible to have users of different domains on a single exchange server?

Do I have to promote the new subdomain to Exchange somehow? If so, how?

EDIT:

I got somewhat further:

Now I am trying to execute `Setup.exe /PrepareSchema /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms` on the child DC [1]. I am logged in as SUB\administrator on the DC, but I get some error like:

- Problem checking status of active directory: No Exchange objects were created because the local computer is not in same domain and site as schema master. Execute setup with parameter /PrepareAD on a computer in the domain `intra` and on site `default-first-site-name`, and wait for replication to complete.

Is this because our server is still a computer in domain `intra`, where he was before he was promoted DC of domain `sub`?

Or is it because I couldn't promote SUB\administrator to a organization admin and schema admin, because such groups do not exist in domain SUB?

[1] http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb125224(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: This looks like you should get your DNS in order. Domain1 needs to be able to lookup Domain2, and vice versa

Comment: I found the problem: I had to execute `Setup.exe /PrepareAD:sub.intra.contoso.com` on the Exchange Server. Then everything worked as a charm.